# set wallpaper button of image from firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to add a set wallpaper button to my app that will set the wallpaper when I pull my image from firebase database. This is what I have so far. I've set the button up to automatically show up on every wallpaper snap shot. I've set a wallpaper in the past when the picture was stored on the phone but cant seem to figure out how to set it when pulling an image from firebase.

```
public class WallpapersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WallpapersAdapter.WallpaperViewHolder> {


private Context mCtx;
private List<Wallpaper> wallpaperList;




public WallpapersAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Wallpaper> wallpaperList) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.wallpaperList = wallpaperList;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public WallpaperViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_wallpapers, parent, false);
    return new WallpaperViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WallpaperViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Wallpaper w = wallpaperList.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(w.title);
    Glide.with(mCtx)
            .load(w.url)
            .into(holder.imageView);
    if(w.isFavorite){
        holder.checkBoxFav.setChecked(true);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return wallpaperList.size();
}

class WallpaperViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;
    CheckBox checkBoxFav;
    ImageButton buttonShare, buttonDownload;
    Button setWallpaper;



    public WallpaperViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        checkBoxFav = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_favorite);
        buttonShare = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_share);
        buttonDownload = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_download);
        setWallpaper = itemView.findViewById(R.id.set_wallpaper);
        setWallpaper.setOnClickListener(this);
        checkBoxFav.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        /*buttonShare.setOnClickListener(this);*/
        /*buttonDownload.setOnClickListener(this);*/





    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.button_share:

                shareWallpaper(wallpaperList.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                break;
            case R.id.button_download:

                downloadWallpaper(wallpaperList.get(getAdapterPosition()));

                break;

            case R.id.set_wallpaper:

                setWallpaper(wallpaperList.get(getAdapterPosition()));

                break;


        }





    }






    private void shareWallpaper(Wallpaper w){
        ((Activity) mCtx).findViewById(R.id.progressbar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Glide.with(mCtx)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(w.url)
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        ((Activity) mCtx).findViewById(R.id.progressbar).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getLocalBitmapUri(resource));
                        mCtx.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "The Wallpaper App"));
                    }



                });


    }

    private Uri getLocalBitmapUri(Bitmap bmp){
        Uri bmpUri = null;


        try {
            File file = new File(mCtx.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                    "the_wallpaper_app_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            out.close();
            bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bmpUri;
    }


    private void downloadWallpaper(final Wallpaper wallpaper){
        ((Activity) mCtx).findViewById(R.id.progressbar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Glide.with(mCtx)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(wallpaper.url)
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        ((Activity) mCtx).findViewById(R.id.progressbar).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                        Uri uri = saveWallpaperAndGetUri(resource, wallpaper.id);
                        if(uri != null){
                            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
                            mCtx.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "The Wallpaper App"));
                        }
                    }

                });
    }

    private Uri saveWallpaperAndGetUri(Bitmap bitmap, String id){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mCtx, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) mCtx, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);

                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", mCtx.getPackageName(), null);
                intent.setData(uri);

                mCtx.startActivity(intent);

            }else{
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mCtx, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 100 );
            }
            return null;

        }

        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/the_wallpaper_app" );
        folder.mkdirs();

        File file = new File(folder, id + ".jpg" );

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            return Uri.fromFile(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;


    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

        if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null){

            Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Please login first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            compoundButton.setChecked(false);
            return;
        }



        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        Wallpaper w = wallpaperList.get(position);

        DatabaseReference dbFavs = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .child("favorites")
                .child(w.category);



        if(b){
            dbFavs.child(w.id).setValue(w);
        }else{
            dbFavs.child(w.id).setValue(null);
        }

    }


}

private void setWallpaper(Wallpaper set) {




    };



}
```

}

Comment: Did you try my answer @T.Freedom , did it help you?

Comment: I working to figure out how to implement your code into my app. any ideas? thanks

Comment: I think you may just give user an option to view image and meanwhile download the image they are viewing on his/her device and when the touch the set wallpaper button, you can just set it using the code in my answer.

Comment: Hey @T.Freedom, if you found my answer useful, do mark it as correct by clicking the V or tick looking button next to the answer, it helps future Stack Overflow readers, and I'd appreciate that. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not directly set the image from database as wallpaper on your android device, for that first you have to download the image to your device and then you can set it as the background wallpaper.

You can use `createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix)` which creates an empty file in the default temporary-file directory, using the given prefix and suffix to generate its name.

[Read more about this here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

If you'd rather want to store the file in your app directory, you can use a code like this:

```java
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "dir_name");
// Create dir if not exists
if(!dir.exists()) dir.mkdirs();

File mFile = new File(dir, "file_name");
```

Also to get bitmap from the file and use it to set as wallpaper, you may use a code similar to this:

```java
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFile.getAbsolutePath());

//after converting it to bitmapDrawable you can set it as background using this

getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable
```

You may also use `WallpaperManager` for this like:

```java
WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setBitmap(resource);
```